# How to integrate Razorpay Payment Gateway in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, razorpay

I am planning to integrate Razorpay Payment Gateway in my client website which has been developed in WordPress in which the scenario will be as follows.

1. The user will fill inquiry form with his requirement.
2. Then depend on customer requirement owner will reply with cost and some code to customer(through mobile/email communication).
3. The customer will go at website's Payment Page where He/She will submit form(name,amount,code as remark and email id) which will redirect to payment gateway page.

At WordPress website the plugin (Razorpay Quick Payments) has implementation details as follows.

1. Add a few custom variables and some markup to a page.
2. Specify the amount, name, description and other custom details as page  metadata.
3. Write [RZP] wherever you want on the post and the button to show up.

The plugin takes over and completes the payment.

I am not getting how to do all these steps.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1** - Create a page and click on "Screen Options" on the top right and Select "Custom Fields" checkbox.

[image]

**Step 2** - You will be able to see a new "Custom Fields" section if you scroll down the page. It contains 2 fields - name and value. Click on "Enter New".

[image]

**Step 3** - Now you will be able to type in the name field, as per the requirements of Razorpay, you have to to enter these 3 values in name field -

- name
- description
- amount

In the "value" field of "amount", you have to enter the amount in rupee you want to charge, if you want to charge INR 1000, you have to enter 1000.

[image]

**Step 4** - In the main text area, type `[RZP]`, save the page and open. You will see "Pay With Razorpay" button.

[image]

Click on the button and you will be able to see different payment options like Debit Card / Credit Card / Netbanking / UPI / Wallet.

[image]

User will have to enter their mobile number and email id to proceed with the payment.

Comment: Thanks Chinmya. Just want to know instead of adding  amount by admin can i give freedom to customer to add amount.My business requirement is like that

Comment: @shrutikharge I am also trying to integrate Razorpay for my wordpress website and my usecase is also to give my customers to choose the amount. Did you find any solution?

Comment: is there any way to prefill email and phone with javascript

Comment: @gegobyte I followed same steps but the button is not showing. can you please assist me?