# Razorpay plugin in wordpress does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am running wordpress 4.9.6 and want to integrate Razorpay payment gateway to my website. I  followed the steps mentioned in the this https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-quick-payments but its not working. No button shows up even after putting [RZP] in my page.

PS: There is already a question in stack overflow on [how to integrate Razorpay payment Gateway in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982010/how-to-integrate-razorpay-payment-gateway-in-wordpress) but that answer did not work for me and I do not have enough reputation to comment there. 
Hence asking as a seperate question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working now! 
Although I added custom fields in my post I dint get it displayed on the page/post.
When I showed custom fields on the post, I got it right. The 'pay with Razorpay' button is displayed.

Comment: hi @AmanSatija, By adding the custom fields on the post, I got it working. ```For this plugin to work correctly, please mention the following items as page metadata (using Screen Options for >4.8) -> Custom Fields:

1. 'name' of the product.
2. 'description' of the product.
3. 'amount' in paise, with a minimum of 1 rupee.```

Comment: @AmanSatija - you can check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982010/how-to-integrate-razorpay-payment-gateway-in-wordpress